# .htaccess not working properly. I want subdomain to be maintained in the url

Tags: php, .htaccess, ftp, web

I am running a website via FTP server.

I am going to revamp this website that is made by someone else.

What I want to do is move the website to the subdomain `archive.domain.com`.

I copied all my files into a subfolder called `archive/` and all the functions seem working.

However, when I access to `http://archive.example.com/some_page`, it automatically redirects to `http://www.example.com/archive/some_page` which is not what I wanted.

I want the domain always to be displayed as `archive.example.com`.

Because if I click the hyperlinks on the webpage, which is relative, it is redirected to the root directory. Say, if I click `/other_page`, it goes to `http://www.example.com/other_page`, not `http://archive.example.com/other_page`.

How can I do this?

My current `.htaccess` file looks like this.

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f   

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^some_page$ /some_page/ [R]
RewriteRule ^some_page/$ ./some_page.php
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your .htaccess file should also exist in the archive directory.
Secondly, the .htaccess file in the archive directory should be adjusted to read

```
    RewriteEngine On  

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f   

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.archive\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.archive.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^some_page$ /some_page/ [R]
    RewriteRule ^some_page/$ ./some_page.php
```

or just remove this 2 lines

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.archive\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.archive.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the first method, and it works perfectly as what I wanted. :) Have a good weekend!